# Automapper maps with wrong property name or I am doing something wrong

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, mapping, automapper

I am trying to map my domain entity to DTO. What I am getting in generated query is wrongly concatenated property name.

**This is my entity class:** (some code is removed for brevity)

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityUnit EntityUnit { get; set; }
}
```

**This my DTO**

```
public class ProductDto : IMapFrom<Product>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public void Mapping(Profile profile)
    {
        profile.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EntityUnit.Name));
    }
}
```

**This is my EntityUnit class:**

```
public class EntityUnit : BaseEntity
{
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**After all this is the generated query:**(on mini-profiler)

[image]

Actually that must be p.UnitId instead of EntityUnitUnitId (which works). Automapper version is 9.0

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: AM doesn't do joins, look at you EF configuration.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu actually it is a good point. Your reminder made me check my **EF** configuration. When I specify UnitId as FK explicitly, I got the right join. Thanks.